# How to remove 'b' from string with python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code

```
path = "/etc/MultiQuickButton/quickbutton_" + x[1] + ".xml"
menu = xml.dom.minidom.parse(path)
self.XML_db = QuickButtonXML(menu)
for e in self.XML_db.getMenu():
                print("**** a ****",a)
                if e[1] == "1":
                    list.append(QuickButtonListEntry('green',(_(str(e[0])),e[0], '1')))
                else:
                    list.append(QuickButtonListEntry('red',(_(str(e[0])),e[0], '')))
```

And I have got this output

```
(b'HbbTV', b'1', b'Menu', '', '', b'from Screens.InfoBarGenerics import InfoBarRedButton\nself.activateRedButton()')
```

I have tried add b and encode() also decode() but with same restaul!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `tuple` of `bytes` objects. The `repr` of a `bytes` object (which is how `tuple` prints its contents) includes the `b` prefix. To fix, just decode all your `bytes` to `str`, e.g., making a new `tuple` of `str` before printing:

```
for a in self.XML_db.getMenu():
    str_a = tuple([x.decode() for x in a])
    print("**** a ****", str_a)
```

If you want the quotation marks removed as well, you'll have to get `tuple` out of the picture so the `str` form, not the `repr` form of each `str` is printed. That's fairly easy though, either by unpacking:

```
for a in self.XML_db.getMenu():
    str_a = [x.decode() for x in a] # No need to convert back to tuple when we'll unpack
    print("**** a ****", *str_a)  # Defaults to space separation; pass sep="somestr"
                                  # to use some other separator
```

or explicit `join`ing:

```
for a in self.XML_db.getMenu():
    str_a = [x.decode() for x in a] # No need to convert back to tuple when we'll join
    print("**** a ****", ', '.join(str_a))  # Comma is for example, use any joiner
```

Comment: Note: `decode`'s default argument is `"utf-8"`. All your example text is ASCII, and UTF-8 is an ASCII superset, so this works. If you need to convert arbitrary binary data to strings and it may not have a meaningful text form, passing `"latin-1"` to `decode` will at least let you map any byte to the matching Unicode ordinal, but the result might be pretty useless/ugly.

Comment: I have tried all example .. But I couldn't get the print of output at all

Comment: @FairBird: I don't know what to tell you. If the original code printed what you claim it printed, and `self.XML_db.getMenu():` wasn't returning some pathological type that looked like a `tuple` of `bytes` but was something entirely different, the changed code would work. My guess is your real code isn't quite the same as what you posted, or is running against different inputs; without a true [MCVE] I can't do much more to help.